# How do I verify If Dexguard has encrypted the class of my Android application?

Tags: android, dexguard

Does dexguard store names of classes and strings which were encrypted. I am using the following command to encrypt the classes

```
-encryptclasses A$B
-encryptstrings A$B
```

Is there a file like bin/proguard/mapping.txt where the class names are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is mapping file where all the entries are saved.
You can find it at below location:
**app\build\outputs\mapping\release**
[image]